# Add UIView to UITabBarItem

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I would like to add a little red dot to a UITabBarItem in my TabBarController to indicate that a certain condition is triggered (in this case the content is filtered), much like Mail little number in Dock indicating how many unread mails you have.

Seems that this cannot be done looking at the Docs. So maybe there is another approach that can use to get this done.

Since the TabBar is always locked at the bottom of the screen I just can overlay another view on top but I am willing to know if there is a smarter way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the badgeValue property of UITabBarItem. Read about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarItem/badgeValue

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't know it was called badge so I just missed it in the docs and couldn't do any search with good results.